# css menu prob in position may be

Tags: html, css, styles

I have added image of what i want and what i have done so far. Help me out please.
I want my list to be in the right side on hover over submenu. Below code is what i have done so far.

This is my css stylesheet.

```
    .menu {     
            border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            width: 200px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            }

    .menu a{ text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;}

    .menu1 {
            border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;
            color: black;
            background-color: #cccccc;
            width: 200px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            }
    .menu1 a{ text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;}

    ul{

        font-size: 13;

        padding: 0;

        list-style: none;

    }

    .ullileft{

        border-radius: 5px; 

        border: 1px solid black;

        background-color: black;  

        float: left;

        width: 200px;

        padding: 5px 10px;

    }

    .ullileft a{width: 180px; text-decoration: none; color: white; font-family: Verdana;  border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black;}


    ul li a{

        width: 180px;

        display: block;

        padding: 5px 10px;

        text-decoration: none;

    }

    ul li a:hover{

        color: black;

        width: 180px;

        background: white;

        border-radius: 5px;

        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    ul li ul{

        display: none;

    }


    ul li:hover ul{

        display: block; /* display the dropdown */

    }

    ul li ul li ul li{

        display: none;

    }
    ul li ul li:hover ul li{

        display: block; /* display the dropdown */

    }
```

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li  class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b>Menu1</b></a>
        </li>
        <li  class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b> Menu2</b></a>
            <ul>

                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'> <b>Submenu1</b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu2  </b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu3  </b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li  class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b> Menu3</b></a>
            <ul>

                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'> <b>Submenu1</b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu2  </b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu3  </b></font></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a>
                            <li  class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a>
                        </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li  class="ullileft">
            <a href="#"><b> Submenu4 </b></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: share your code, then we can help

Comment: check this, http://htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/ , http://www.cssscript.com/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/

Comment: Hey @Siddharth I have posted my code. Please help me out.

Comment: @Aru I have tried doing as given in your links. But unable to get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `.menu` `position: relative;`, add a new rule `.menu > ul` and make it `position: absolute;` to remove the submenu list out of the document flow and position it relative to the parent  `.menu`. You then set `.menu > ul` to `top: 0;` and `left: 100%;` to place it to the top right of the parent `.menu`.

```css
.menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu1 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.menu1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
    font-size: 13;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.ullileft {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.ullileft a {
    width: 180px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a {
    width: 180px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    width: 180px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    /* display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    /* display the dropdown */
}
.menu > ul {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b>Menu1</b></a></li>
        <li class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b> Menu2</b></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'> <b>Submenu1</b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu2  </b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu3  </b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ullileft"><a href="#"><b> Menu3</b></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'> <b>Submenu1</b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu2  </b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu"><a href=""><font size='3'><b> Submenu3  </b></font></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List1 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List2 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List3 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List4 </a></li>
                        <li class="menu1"><a href=""> List5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ullileft"> <a href="#"><b> Submenu4 </b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css

```
 .menu ul
  {margin-left:200px;
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:-25px;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qzo3wprk/1/)